# $z^5 = -32$ Where I am doing wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I believe my steps are correct but not sure why I am not getting the right answer. Following is my solution.

\begin{align*}
z^5 & = (-2)^5 \cdot (1 + 0\cdot i)\\
 & = (-2)^5 (\cos(2\pi k) + i\sin(2\pi k))  & k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
 & = (-2)^5 e^{2\pi ki} & 
\end{align*}

Hence,
$$z = -2e^{2i\pi k/5}, k = 0,1,2,3,4$$

However, the answer is $z = -2, e^{\pm i\pi/5}, e^{\pm 3i\pi/5}$ (see below).

[image]

Edit: I still don't understand why my solution is wrong. Let $z = -2e^{\frac{2i\pi}{5}}$. Then
\begin{align*}
z^5 & = -32e^{2\pi i}\\
& = -32 (\cos 2\pi + i\sin 2\pi)\\
& = -32 \cdot (1 + 0\cdot i)\\
&= -32
\end{align*}

Comment: The answer provided to you is wrong.  The last two classes of solutions need a factor of $2$ as well.  Aside from that, they differ from your solutions by factors of $e^{2 \pi i}$.

Comment: I think you meant to say $e^{i\pi /5}$?

Comment: Also, I am confused. So my answers are right?

Comment: Yes, your answers are right, although your use of $-2$ means that they're not presented in a standard form.

Comment: "Standard" you mean "conventional"? Or "correct"?

Comment: I meant "conventional."

Answer (score 1):

That is not the actual trigonometric form of $-32$. The radius needs to be a positive number. You also don't need to account for every possible $k$ among the angles.

You should write $z^5 = 2^5 (\cos(\pi) + i \sin \pi)$ and that should lead you to the correct solutions.

Comment: Forgot that it has to be positive. Thank you! Will accept when it lets me. :)

Comment: Hold on, couldn't that be the right trigonometric form of $1$?